# Asset transforms saved on S3 storage

Tags: assets, image-transforms, s3

I've just set up an S3 bucket and have a transform in my template. Should these transformed images be saved on S3? It doesn't look like they are, however my template is pulling out an S3 URL:

```
<img src="{{ asset.getUrl(resize) }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth(resize) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(resize) }}" alt="A photograph of {{ entry.title }}" class="grayscale grayscale-fade wp-post-image ral-mugshot">
```

When using a base image at http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/rallyagency/princess-leia-princess-leia-walking-in-new-york-is-just-plain-awesome.jpeg, my template outputs this:

```
<img src="http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/rallyagency/_200x200_crop_center-center_75/princess-leia-princess-leia-walking-in-new-york-is-just-plain-awesome.jpeg?mtime=20141217123237" width="200" height="200" alt="A photograph of Ali Meredith" class="grayscale grayscale-fade wp-post-image ral-mugshot">
```

Note the addition of the directory **_200x200_crop_center-center_75** in the path - that doesn't exist on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, they should get created on S3 and also cached locally.

But if I try to load https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/rallyagency/_200x200_crop_center-center_75/princess-leia-princess-leia-walking-in-new-york-is-just-plain-awesome.jpeg?mtime=20141217123237 directly, I'm getting an "Access Denied" error, so it looks like you've got some S3 permission issues.

Comment: Yes exactly. I've got a policy set for public read access and I have a key set up for full access that Craft uses. Presumably the issue is with the key, not the public policy?

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Looks like my access key worked but wasn't up-to-date with the latest IAM setup in AWS. Now sorted.

Comment: Brad, what if we are using Cloudfront in conjunction with s3? In that case I don't think we would want craft caching the images, right?